# MySQL select multiple date range

Tags: mysql, date, date-range

I have a table with 2 dates: startDate and EndDate

I pass to my query 2 dates and I want to check if in this date range the offer are available.

I have an offer that is valid From 1 may 2019 to 30 may 2019.
When I search in offers, I want to show this only if the date range that I pass is included in the date range of the offer.

- OFFER From 1 may 2019 to 30 may 2019
- Value pass: 01 jan 2019 to 4 jan 2019 NO SHOW
- Value pass: 28 april 2019 to 2 may 2019 NO SHOW
- ***Value pass: 10 may 2019 to 12 may 2019 ONLY SHOW IN THIS CASE***
- Value pass: 29 may 2019 to 2 june 2019 NO SHOW
- Value pass: 10 nov 2019 to 12 now 2019 NO SHOW

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please tag your question with the language / product you're using and show how you've attempted to solve your problem so far.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for MySQL.

```
date_from < '2019-10-05' AND date_to > '2019-10-12'
```